# const correct laundering of pods (plain old data)

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, strict-aliasing, const-correctness

To get around aliasing and byte reinterpretation rules, I have a utility function called `T* landry_pod<T>(void*)` that pretends to copy bytes around and create new objects.  It compiles down to nothing under optimization, as every compiler can see I put the bytes back where they started.

```
template<class T>
T* laundry_pod( void* data ){
  static_assert( std::is_pod<T>{} ); // or more verbose replacement as pod is gone
  char tmp[sizeof(T)];
  std::memcpy( tmp, data, sizeof(T) );
  T* r = ::new(data) T;
  std::memcpy( data, tmp, sizeof(T) );
  return r;
}
```

This ensures the `sizeof(T)` bits data points at are identical, but returns a pointer to an object of type `T` there.  It is a standards compliant way to do `T* r = (T*)data;` when `data` just points at bits but *not* an actual object.  It optimizes down to 0 instructions at runtime.

Sadly, while it does nothing at runtime, it logically cannot be used on a `const` buffer.

This is my attempt to modify it to work with `const` input and output:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<T>{}, bool> = true, class In>
T* laundry_pod( const In* data ){
  static_assert( sizeof(In)==1 ); // really, In should be byte or char or similar
  static_assert( std::is_pod<T>{} ); // or more verbose replacement as pod is gone
  std::byte tmp[sizeof(T)];
  std::memcpy( tmp, data, sizeof(T) ); // copy bytes out
  for(std::size_t i =0; i<sizeof(T); ++i)
    data[i].~In(); // destroy const objects there // is this redundant?
  auto* r = ::new( (void*)data ) std::remove_const_t<T>; // cast away const on data (!)
  std::memcpy( r, tmp, sizeof(T) ); // copy same bytes back
  return r;
}
```

here I destroy the const objects (well bytes) then construct a new object in their place.

The above should optimize to 0 instructions (try it), but I had to cast away const when I created `r`.

If `data` is pointing to a contiguous buffer of const char or byte, is destroying those objects sufficient to permit me to reuse the storage and remain in defined behaviour land?  Or would simply creating new objects be sufficient?  Or am I doomed?

Assume noone uses the old `In` pointer to access the original bytes before hand.

Comment: It's not clear what this function is supposed to actually accomplish.

Comment: @nicol clarified by adding non-const version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of your question is it defined behavior to reuse the storage of a `const` object? The answer is no, according to [basic.life#9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.life#9):

> Creating a new object at the storage location that a const object with static, thread, or automatic storage duration occupies or, at the storage location that such a const object used to occupy before its lifetime ended results in undefined behavior.
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct B {
>   B();
>   ~B();
> };
>
> const B b;
>
> void h() {
>   b.~B();
>   new (const_cast<B*>(&b)) const B;             // undefined behavior
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Ostensibly this is because the data may be placed in read-only memory. So it is not surprising that trying to modify `const` data is a no-op.

Comment: The data might not be placed anywhere at all. (Are you sure you mean "ostensibly"? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostensibly)

Comment: It's true in some cases that it can be optimized out and nothing is placed in the binary at all; however given the context of the question the assumption is that there is some storage to use at all.

Comment: @user not really, the fact there doesn't have to be storage is also on topic; even if ODR used, the identity produced can still be fake.  But this answers my question directly.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, the original function actually isn't the identity at all- you're still causing a read *and write* of the original buffer, which may have different semantics to a plain read in concurrent usage scenarios. Particularly, multiple threads calling `laundry_pod` at the same time on the same buffer is UB.